# Facing "System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred." error abruptly

Tags: c#

This is my code which was working successfully from last 3 years, however it throwing error sometime (not everytime) since last 3 days.

Here is the code:

```
HttpResponseMessage responseResult = client.GetAsync("api/v1/treatments?search=treatmentStartDate%21%3E" + StartTxdate + ",treatmentStartDate%3C%21" + EndTxdate + "").Result;
```

Below is complete exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at TabloDialysisMachine.MachineProgram.GetTabloApiData()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---
```

I analysis this found below output:

1. When I debug through code it throws above mentioned exception.
2. When I request through Postman this shows Error: Request Timed Out

First of all I want to know problem is my side or client side as same code was working fine from last  years.
Also I want to know here Request Time Out means request is not able to connect API Endpoint or Data Process took more time than expected.
Why It is showing different in Postman compare to code debugging.
What can be solution if issue is my side or If other side then How can I show issue is other side.

Comment: "Why It is showing different in Postman compare to code debugging" - it's not, really. The task is cancelled (the inner exception) because the client-side timeout has fired. It sounds like the API you're calling is broken somehow. (If you want to know *exactly* what's happening at a network level, I'd suggest using Wireshark. That will give more information about whether the client was able to connect to the server at all, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root Cause for Exception:

Recently whenever I am requesting client, I was getting response within 90 seconds. Now as request is processing large data on client end it was taking more than 90 seconds. Whenever it was taking more 90 seconds we were facing exception.
By default HttpClient timeout is 90 seconds. After 90 second timeout was happening so we were receiving this exception.

Resolution:
In this case we added HttpClient timeout manually for 5 mins, and It worked fine. Below is code to add HttpClient timeout.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```